# Tensorflow LSTM model testing

Tags: testing, machine-learning, tensorflow, test-data, lstm

I'm new to LSTM and Tensorflow, and I'm trying to use an LSTM model to learn and then classify some huge data set that I have. (I'm not worried about the accuracy my intention is to learn). 
I tried to implement the model in a similar way as in the PTB word prediction tutorial that uses LSTM. 
The code in the tutorial (https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) uses the below line to run the session using the model

```
 cost, state, _ = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, eval_op],
                                 {m.input_data: x,
                                  m.targets: y,
                                  m.initial_state: state})
```

I modified this for my example as below (to get the logits and work with it):

```
  cost, state, _,output,logits = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, eval_op, m.output,m.logits],
                                 {m.input_data: x,
                                  m.targets: y,
                                  m.initial_state: state})
```

So my questions if someone could help are as below:

- How can the model built while training be used for testing? What
  exactly is happening when 3 models are being used by the tutorial one for each test, train and validation?
- What about the targets while testing(if I don't know them, say in a classification problem). What changes in the run_epoch () can be done in a way to use the model built during training.
- Just another question: It's difficult to debug tensorflow graphs ( and I found it difficult to understand the tensorboard visualizer too) And I didn't find good resource for learning tensorflow (the website seems to be lacking structure/ documentation) What other resources/ debugging methods are there?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps, these simple LSTM examples address your questions about the basic LSTM in TensorFlow: https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow or https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/7_lstm.py

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question to help anyone who ends up here:
During validation/testing, indicate to the runepoch() that it is validation/ testing phase (using  a bool or some other way).
Don't call the cost op (as this is the only operation that requires the targets.) So modified code for validation/ testing phase will look something like this:

```
 state, _,output,logits = session.run([m.final_state, eval_op, m.output,m.logits],
                             {m.input_data: x,
                              m.initial_state: state})
```

make use of the logits later for calcluating the accuracy.